# Using Sed to get the 12th character from the third line of a file

Tags: bash, sed

I need a way read the 12th character from the 3rd line in a text file using bash.  Is there a way to do this with sed?

Edit:  Looking over all of the answers, the ones that use `awk` or `gawk` look easier.  However, I cannot get them to work with variables.  I typed
`gawk -F '' 'NR==3{print $VALUE}' file` when `$VALUE=12` and line 3 of the file was `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` put in just prints the whole line.  Do I need to put quotes or parentheses anywhere?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  This is sufficiently simple to answer that it is almost too much effort to chastise you with questions such as 'what have you tried'.  On the whole, you should show what you've tried.  Please note that you should normally provide an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Answer (score 3):

Note: Both solutions in this answer don't support multi byte characters. Only ASCII.

---

With GNU awk it is pretty simple:

```
gawk -F '' 'NR==3{print $12}' file
```

Setting the field delimiter to an empty char splits the input lines into characters.

With `sed` it could look like this:

```
sed -n '3{s/.\{11\}//;s/\(.\).*/\1/p}' file
```

First remove the leading 11 characters using `s/.\{11\}//` then keep the 12th character and remove everything behind it using `s/\(.\).*/\1/`. `p` prints the remaining 12th character. You see, the `awk` solution is simpler. ;)

PS: The above `sed` solution can be simplified as [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41070276/171318) showed.

Comment: ++ for the simple `awk`-based solution, but note that, sadly, it is only robust if you use _GNU_ `awk`:
Neither Mawk (default Awk on Ubuntu) nor BSD/macOS Awk are locale-aware (they invariably treat individual _bytes_ as _characters_). Additionally, BSD/macOS Awk doesn't recognize `-F ''`, though you can use `-v FS=` instead. Verify with `printf 'hü' | awk -v FS= 'NR==1 {print $2}'`: if your Awk is locale-aware, you'll see `ü`.

Comment: @mklement0 Good point, thanks for the comment

Comment: @mklement0 wrt `you can use -v FS= instead`, the result of doing that is still not robust because while gawk splits on characters given a null FS, that's not defined by POSIX so any awk can do whatever it likes with a null FS. IMHO put the `gawk-specific` stamp on the whole thing as hek2mgl has done and move on :-).

Comment: @EdMorton: You are correct: POSIX states: ["If FS is a null string, the behavior is unspecified."](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html). Pragmatically speaking, however, `-v FS=` works with GNU Awk, Mawk, and BSD/macOS Awk to split input records into characters. It is only the - separate - character-encoding issue that makes this a GNU Awk-only solution.

Comment: What about /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or nawk or tawk or .... I really have no idea if it works with them or not, I'm just saying there's at least as many awks out there as the three you did mention so I disagree with the characterization that that doesn't matter.

Comment: @EdMorton: Fair enough; let's summarize: the character splitting works for the implementations I mentioned, with the limitation with respect to character encoding I mentioned. It may not work for other implementations.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -n '3 s/^.\{11\}\(.\).*/\1/p' text.file
```

The `-n` means 'do not print by default'.  On line 3, match 11 characters, capture 1 (the 12th), match the rest, replace with the captured character, print.  You could quit after line 3 if you wanted to:

```
sed -n '3 {s/^.\{11\}\(.\).*/\1/p;q;}' text.file
```

That way, `sed` doesn't waste time reading and ignoring the rest of the file.

And, if you like contorted programming, you could use:

```
sed -n '3 {s/^\(\(.\)\{12\}\).*/\2/p;q;}' text.file
```

The advantage of this is that 12 appears in the command line, so if you change your mind and want 15, or 9, instead of 12, you can change it directly — indeed, with care, it could be a shell parameter that you use to hold the number, and you don't have to 'subtract 1' before using it, or special case 1.  How does it work?  There are two nested captures; the outer one is 12 characters long, but the inner one is just one character, and because it gets repeated, only the last match counts as far as the replacement operation is concerned — hence `\2` in the replacement supplies the 12th character.

Comment: Stuff like this is a good argument for the `-E` switch, `sed -nE '3{s/.{11}(.).*/\1/p;q;}`, note you don't need the `^` because regex's are leftmost-longest and there's no chance of a mismatch.

Comment: Opinions vary.  You're entitled to yours.  I disagree about removing `^` vehemently, and I've worked without `-E` for so long that it doesn't worry me not using it.

Answer (score 1):

One can pipe sed to cut:

sed is used to extract the line, while cut is used to extract the character:

```
sed -n '3{p;q}' | cut -c 12
```

Comment: ++ for an answer in the spirit of Unix. Sadly, as of GNU coreutils v8.26, `cut` still blindly assumes that characters are _bytes_, irrespective of the active locale's character encoding (typically, UTF-8).
Thus, with _GNU_ `cut` (Linux), this won't work for you if your lines contain non-ASCII characters. By contrast, BSD/macOS `cut` _does_ respect the active character encoding.
Verify with the following command: `printf 'hü' | cut -c2`; if `cut` is locale-aware, you'll see `ü`.

Comment: Ah well, I wasn't aware of this. Well I could properly have told myself. `-m` could be added as with `wc` to count multibyte characters, but that should have been done 15 years ago.

Comment: It is indeed baffling that GNU `cut` still doesn't support this.

Answer (score 1):

three other `awk` solutions, first two are `gawk` specific.

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="11 1"} NR==3{print $2}'

$ gawk 'NR==3{print gensub(/^.{11}(.).*/,"\\1",1)}'
```

this should work on all `awk`s for ASCII charsets as commented below

```
$ awk 'NR==3{print substr($0,12,1)}'
```

Comment: ++ for simple `awk` alternatives: the 1st command is _GNU_ Awk-specific due to use of the nonstandard `FIELDWIDTHS` variable (as an aside: as of at least v4.1.3: there's no need to define any 3rd field-width value, so I suggest removing `100`).
The 2nd command is POSIX-compliant in principle, but, unfortunately, neither Mawk (default Awk on Ubuntu) nor BSD/macOS Awk handle non-ASCII characters correctly. Try `printf 'hü' | awk 'NR==1{print substr($0,2,1)}'` with your Awk: if the output is `ü`, then your Awk handles multi-byte characters correctly.

Comment: P.S: Your Awk answers are generally excellent, but they often use GNU Awk-specific features without saying so, which can lead to frustration in readers trying your solutions with other Awk implementations.
Note that it is not just non-Linux platforms such as BSD/macOS that do not come with GNU Awk, but also at least one major Linux distro: Ubuntu, which ships with Mawk (presumably, for performance reasons).
GNU Awk has many useful extensions, and it's understandable to focus on it, but please say so. A simple solution would be to change your catchphrase to "GNU Awk to the rescue!".

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '3!d; /^...........\(.\).*/ s::\1:' FILE
```